# values of array gets changed automatically after taking string input

Tags: c++, arrays, buffer, buffer-overflow

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long int m,i;
    cin>>m;
    float first=0,second=0,disp=0;
    int arr[m];
    char ch[m];
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
    cin>>arr[i];
    }
    cout<<" before="<<arr[0]<<endl;
    cin>>ch;
    cout<<" after="<<arr[0]<<endl;
    //puts(ch);
    return 0;
}
```

First i insert elements in an array then Print the zeroth index of an array after that i take string input .Suddenly what happened!. My zeroth index of array got changed!!!.
How it's possible ,Would anyone care to explain this

[image: output of a program in c++]

values of the `arr[0]` got Changed, why?

Comment: please post the code here.

Comment: that's not valid c++.   you can't allocate an array based on a value determined at runtime.

Comment: in new compiler we can do that .

Comment: in new compiler we can do that . Even gcc compiler in linux(ubuntu) also allow you to create the size of array at run time.  Even online sites like geeksforgeeks ,hackerrank ,spoj allows you to do that.!

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long int m,i;
    cin>>m;   
    float first=0,second=0,disp=0;
    int arr[m];     
    char ch[m];
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
        cin>>arr[i];
        }
    cout<<" before="<<arr[0]<<endl;
    cin>>ch;
    cout<<" after="<<arr[0]<<endl;
    //puts(ch);
 return 0;
}

Comment: It's a C feature that some C++ compilers allow as an extension, but it's not standard C++.

Comment: see my code @SouravGhosh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you input too many characters for `cin >> ch;`. Since `m == 40`, you declared it as `char ch[40]`. This allows you to enter 39 characters (not 40 because of the trailing `'\0'` character), but you entered much more than that, so it wrote outside the array boundary, which results in undefined behavior. In this case, it overflowed into the `arr` array.

I suggest you use `std::string` rather than a `char` array, then it will automatically expand to the proper size.

Comment: but when i change the size of array to " char arr[m+1]"  then it works preety fine .So why its affecting the array when we already stored in arr and specially the zero index.!

Comment: The two arrays are next to each other in memory. So when you write outside the `ch` array, it writes into the `arr` array. `arr[0]` is the first thing after the end of the `ch` array.

Comment: Yeah it worked  fine while i am using string. but i want an explanation why it doesn't work when i use character array . but it altered the integer array value...

Comment: I explained why in my answer. You allocated space for 10 characters, but you entered more than 10 characters, so it wrote outside the `ch` array and started writing into the `arr` array.

Comment: no i haven't allocate 10 character space .i allocated according to need of the user. char   arr[m]. i allocated m bytes to character array

Comment: And `m = 10` in the example you showed, so you allocated 10 characters.

Comment: How many characters did you type? Remember that when you use a `char` array to hold a string, there's an extra null byte at the end. So `char ch[m]` only allows `m-1` characters to be entered.

Comment: It would be better if you posted a plain text transcript instead of an image, it's much easier to read, and then I can easily copy what you entered to count the characters. But it looks like at least 50 characters, so it doesn't fit into `char ch[40]`

Comment: actually when i use small values it worked fine .but for large values it doesn't give me the correct value of a[0];

Comment: It's undefined behavior, **anything** can happen. That means that sometimes you don't see the bug.

Answer (score 1):

You have stumbled upon a **Buffer Overflow**. Wikipedia has a basic example, as well as more details on this subject. ([Read more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow))

It's what happens when you overrun the **ch** array's boundary and write to it's adjacent memory locations (which in this case happened to be the **arr** array).